# No such method 'AngleCosine' for invocant of type 'Rat'

Tags: raku

I am trying to write a test method to print to screen the cosine of an angle given in degrees.

What I eventually would like is to be able to address the following as

```
say 45.AngleCosine;
```

without the .new stuff, like

```
say .7.cos;
```

How do I ditch the .new stuff?

This is what I have so far:

```
   class Angle {
       has Numeric $.degrees;

       method AngleCosine( $debug = False )  {
          my Str     $SubName = &?ROUTINE.name;
          my Numeric $radians = self.degrees * π / 180;
          my Numeric $cosine  = $radians.cos;

          if $debug  {
             print "$SubName debugging:\n";
             print "   self    = <" ~ self.degrees ~ ">\n";
             print "   radians = <$radians>\n";
             print "   Cosine of " ~ self.degrees ~  " degrees is <" ~ $cosine ~ ">\n";
          }
          return $cosine;
       }
    }

my $x = Angle.new( degrees=> 45 );
say $x.AngleCosine;
0.7071067811865476

say $x.AngleCosine( True );
AngleCosine debugging:
 self    = <45>
 radians = <0.7853981633974483>
 Cosine of 45 degrees is <0.7071067811865476>
0.7071067811865476

print Angle.new( degrees => 45 ).AngleCosine( True ) ~ "\n";
AngleCosine debugging:
   self    = <45>
   radians = <0.7853981633974483>
   Cosine of 45 degrees is <0.7071067811865476>
0.7071067811865476
```

Comment: Hi @Todd I tried your script down to the line `say $x.AngleCosine;` and got the error `SORRY!=== Error while compiling {...filename here...} Variable '$x' is not declared` . If I try to add a `my $x;` line before invoking your method, I get the error `No such method 'AngleCosine' for invocant of type 'Any'
  in block <unit> at {...filename here...}`

Comment: Hi Jubilatious1,  Good catch, I forgot to copy over the declarations of $x.  I hvae corrected it now.  Thank you!  -T

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The problem

```
45.AngleCosine
```

- `45` is a [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)).
- `45` constructs a value of the built in class `Int`.
- There is no built in routine named `AngleCosine` (in `Int` or anywhere else).

---

In standard Raku, syntax of the form `foo.bar` denotes a ["method call"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)).

Slightly simplifying, this means Rakudo should:

- **Presume there's a routine** corresponding to `AngleCosine`.
- **Discover [candidate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region#Candidate_solution) routines** corresponding to the name `AngleCosine` (and sort them into order, with the fittest candidates listed first).
- **Try [binding](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-binder) to routine candidates** in order of their fitness, and as soon as one successfully binds, call it and consider the call resolved.
- **Fail the resolution attempt** if no candidates successfully bound, throwing a "No such method" exception.

---

The candidate discovery step is driven by the syntactic form of `bar` in `foo.bar`:

- If `bar` starts with a letter (or underscore), Rakudo will start looking for methods associated with `foo`. In your example, `bar` is `AngleCosine` and `foo` is `45`, so the search will start by looking for methods named `AngleCosine` in the `Int` class (`45` is an instance of the `Int` class).
- When searching for methods associated with an object, Rakudo will look at each of the classes included in the object's "Method Resolution Order" to discover candidates. In your example, `foo` is `45`, so the MRO is as listed by `45.^mro`. This displays `((Int) (Cool) (Any) (Mu))`.

---

In standard Raku there is no method named `AngleCosine` declared in any of the classes `Int`, `Cool`, `Any`, or `Mu`. Thus Raku displays the error message:

```
No such method 'AngleCosine' for invocant of type 'Int'
```

## Solutions

- Stick with the precise syntax `45.AngleCosine`. This is fraught and complicated, and will be discussed last in this answer.
- Use a non-method call solution. For examples, see answers by @p6steve and @ValleLukas.
- Use a suitably initialized variable (eg `$x`) on the left of the method call `.` instead of a value literal (eg `45`). See the **Solutions that change the `foo` of `foo.bar`** section below.
- Use a suitably altered mention of the routine (eg `&AngleCosine`) on the right of the method call `.`. See the **Solutions that change the `bar` of `foo.bar`** section below.

## Solutions that change the `foo` of `foo.bar`

You could change the declaration of your `Angle` class and then instantiate and use an `Angle` instance like so:

```
class Angle {
  has Numeric $.degrees;
  method AngleCosine { 'do something with $!degrees' }
}

my Angle $x .= new: degrees => 45;

say $x.AngleCosine; # 'do something with $!degrees'
```

But you've said you want a solution "without the .new stuff".

Another option is using a [coercion type](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Coercion_type).

Until recently you could only use coercion types with routine calls. But with Rakudo versions from the last month or so something like the following should work:

```
class Angle {
  has Numeric $.degrees;
  method COERCE ( Numeric $degrees ) { self.new: :$degrees }
  method AngleCosine { 'do something with $!degrees' }
}

my Angle() $x = 45;

say $x.AngleCosine; # do something with $!degrees
```

## Solutions that change the `bar` of `foo.bar`

If you were willing to abandon all of OO except for the `lhs.rhs` syntax, you could write:

```
sub AngleCosine ($_) { 'do something with $_' }

say 45.&AngleCosine; # do something with $_
```

This works because the prepended `&` directs Raku to presume the routine that follows it:

- Is *not* a method, but instead a subroutine that is to be treated *as if it were* a method, passing the value on the LHS of the `.` as the routine's first argument;
- Should *not* be discovered by searching *classes*;
- Should, if the first character *after* the `&` is a letter (or underscore)  -- which is indeed the case with `&AngleCosine` -- be discovered by looking in the lexical subroutine namespace.

---

If you wanted to move back toward OO by declaring an *actual method*, but still keep it *outside* of any class, you could write:

```
my method AngleCosine { 'do something with $_' }

say 45.&AngleCosine; # do something with $_
```

The first line, declaring a method *outside* of a `class` construct, and with a `my`, installs the method in the exact same namespace as non-method subroutines, so the calling syntax and effect is the same as the example just explained above.

---

If you wanted to stick with having an `AngleCosine` method in your `Angle` class, you can use the above technique of using a prepended `&` to switch off the automatic class based method resolution, but then directly inline a *block* that manually dispatches to the method declared in your `Angle` class:

```
class Angle {
  method AngleCosine { 'do something with self' }
}

say 45.&{ Angle.^find_method('AngleCosine')[0]($_) }
```

Hopefully that is suitably horrific looking code that you are never tempted to even think you have to go this route, and will forgive me for not explaining it further.

## Solutions using the precise syntactic form `45.AngleCosine`

So finally we arrive at solutions that exactly fit what you suggested you really wanted.

First, you can *always* change *any* aspect of Raku's syntax or semantics via slangs. But for most problems, doing so is like using a nuclear power station to power a light bulb. I'm not going to cover how a slang might solve this problem because it would be essentially absurd to do so.

Which leaves one last approach: [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls), or more specifically "monkey typing". Hopefully you get the picture from the name; it means monkeying around with types, and is generally a *very* dodgy thing to do, a technique that will mess things up if you don't know exactly what you're doing, and maybe even then.

Raku *will* let you monkey with typing, despite it being dodgy, rather than simply banning it. But to protect the innocent, Raku insists that you make it *absolutely clear* that you really want to do this dodgy thing. So you have to use a LOUD pragma (either the specific [`use MONKEY-TYPING;`](https://docs.raku.org/language/pragmas#index-entry-MONKEY-TYPING__pragma) or the general `use MONKEY;`).

With that preamble out of the way, here's the code:

```
role Angle { method AngleCosine { 'type has been monkey patched' } }
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class Int does Angle {}

say 45.AngleCosine; # type has been monkey patched
```

This code `augment`s the `Int` class to add an `AngleCosine` method.

Note that you *can't* add new *attributes* or parent classes to `Int`. Once a class has been composed, which for an ordinary `class` declaration occurs immediately after the `}` at the end of the `class` declaration has been encountered, its list of attributes and parents is permanently fixed.

So this approach can't be used to inject your `$.degrees` attribute, and you have to put the method in a `role` instead of a `class`. (A `role` is mostly like a `class` but is generally more versatile, and this is an example of when you can do something if you declare a bunch of methods and/or attributes with the keyword `role`, but not if you use the keyword `class`.)

---

Not only is this solution unable to add an attribute or parent class, but it's still extremely inappropriate for most use cases due to *other* serious problems. In a sense it's even worse than solving your problem with a slang, because what I've shown will barely power a light bulb, and, much worse, might well melt down.

But it's vastly simpler than writing a slang, at least for very simple cases, and if you don't care about a potential melt down, maybe, just maybe, it's the right thing. In particular, it can make sense for code that hopefully works most of the time but is allowed to occasionally fail or do strange things for strange reasons. You've said your context is testing, and if you mean one off testing, then perhaps monkey typing is good enough.

## Why the `Rat:D` type constraint didn't do what you wanted

This is a "bonus" section related to your original question which I'll repeat here in abbreviated form:

> I am trying to write a test method to print to screen the cosine of an angle given in degrees.

```
class Angle {
    method AngleCosine( Rat:D: --> Rat:D ) { ... }
}

say (45.0).AngleCosine

No such method 'AngleCosine' for invocant of type 'Rat'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

> What am I doing wrong?

You might reasonably ask why explicitly specifying the invocant type `Rat:D` in your `AngleCosine` method didn't do what you intended.

As discussed in the previous **Solutions using the precise syntactic form `45.AngleCosine`** section, this is known as "monkey typing" and it's a dodgy thing to do. So while Raku *will* let you monkey with the typing, it insists that you make it absolutely clear that you want to do so by using a `MONKEY` pragma.

You might then still reasonably ask why Rakudo didn't produce a helpful error message explaining that it won't work, and what to do about it (eg "Perhaps you want the `MONKEY` pragma?").

And *that* is because it *can* be useful to explicitly specify an invocant type. So Rakudo doesn't complain about code just because it explicitly specifies an invocant type. For example, if you don't *directly contradict* the enclosing class, but merely refine the type, eg to be a sub-class, then the method will work when the invocant accords with the refinement, which adds nuance to the binder stage described in an earlier section. And that can be useful. So there's no need for an error message in that scenario.

Which leaves us with the question why Rakudo doesn't display an error when the explicitly specified invocant class *directly contradicts* the enclosing class, as it did in your case? Why didn't it just guess you meant to monkey patch, and provide guidance on what you can do?

And that's because it can't know *for sure* that your contradiction of the enclosing class is inappropriate. Sometimes it is.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on raku modules [Physics::Unit](https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Unit) and [Physics::Measure](https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Measure) and I recently added Physics::Measure::Angle types.

As you can see in the synopsis of Physics::Measure,

```
#Angles use degrees/minutes/seconds or decimal radians
    my $θ1 ♎️ <45°30′30″>;      #45°30′30″ 
    my $θ2 ♎️ '2.141 radians';  #'2.141 radian'

# Trigonometric functions sin, cos and tan (and arc-x) handle Angles
    my $sine = sin( $θ1 );      #0.7133523847299412
    my $arcsin = asin( $sine, units => '°' ); #45°30′30″
#NB. Provide the units => '°' tag to tell asin you want degrees back
```

[Admittedly this is only implemented as a sub call right now, not the method format you wanted `say $θ1.sin;` I have put this as an [issue](https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Measure/issues/34) for a future enhancement]

There is a little bit of work going on behind the scenes, I use these ideas (which you are welcome to view / copy / adapt from the module source code)...

- The Measure parent type class to combine value and units for various child type classes such as Angle
- Overriding math operators with multi infix s (for +-*/) that detect the type and handle the units - also extend trig functions such as sin, cos, tan
- Introducing the ♎️ emoji as a means to side step the 'new' construct (so `my $θ2 ♎️ '2.141 radians'` is shorthand for `my $θ2 .= Angle.new(value = 2.141, units => 'radians');`
- Providing the .in method to convert from eg. radians to degrees (the built in trig functions only handle radians) - fr example here are lines from Measure.rakumod

  ```
  multi sin( Angle:D $a ) is export {
      sin( $a.in('radian').value );
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

`self` referes to the invocant object: (see: [raku doc for self](https://docs.raku.org/syntax//self.html)). To call a method, you have to define the class. For more info about class method in raku see also: [class method in raku](https://andrewshitov.com/2018/10/31/class-methods-in-perl-6/) and [raku doc for method](https://docs.raku.org/type/Method)

```
class Angle {
    method AngleCosine( Rat:D $x --> Rat:D )  {
        my Numeric $radians = $x*π/180;
        say "self   = <$x>";
        say "radians = <$radians>";
        $radians.cos.Rat;
    }
}

say Angle.AngleCosine: 45.0;
```

Comment: Hi Valle,   Thank you for the help!  I correct my code in the original post. Do you know how I can ditch the .new?  -T

Comment: @Todd that was not in the original question. If that's what you want, it would be best to reformulate it and/or check out documentation for Callable / `CALL-ME` https://docs.raku.org/type/Callable#method_CALL-ME

Comment: I do believe that Valle has show me that I can not do a `46.cos` style method from a custom class.  I must send the method an object that is declared from the method's class.  (That was a mouth full.)   So I am stuck with .new